# How to reference a cell in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to google script and have little experience, so I hope you can help me.

```
I have this script: 

function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Staffing Data');
  var r = s.getRange('B:B');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]=='DE')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};
```

And I use it to identify if the column B contains the given value. 
Would it be possible to have the 'DE'  reference to a cell in the spreadsheet? 
I would like it to reference the cell A1 in the sheet "Staffing Data", this way I could change the value directly from there without going into the script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--) if(v[i][0]=='DE') s.deleteRow(i+1);`

Also this `var r = s.getRange(1,2,s.getLastRow());` is better than this `var r = s.getRange('B:B');` as the latter often returns nulls from bottom of data to maxrows.

Just to be clear: `var startRow=2;var r= s.getRange(sr,1,s.getLastRow()-startRow+1);` if your range is not starting at the top

You can also delete like this `var d=0;for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) if(v[i][0]=='DE') s.deleteRow(i+1-d++);`

Comment: Thanks for looking into the first bit. indeed the option you are suggesting looks better. 
As for the 'DE' part, I'm not sure if I'm following. Could I get that connected to a cell in my spreadsheet? And if yes, how?

Comment: If I want to change the 'DE' to 'EL' for example I would always have to go into the script to change it. By making it reference to a cell I could do it much easier from there

Comment: Yeh sure you do something like `var s=somesheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();... if(v[i][0]==s);` Or you could make it a parameter to the function with `function delRows(s) {var s=s||'default';` so that if you don't supply it then in becomes.  Actually, in ES6 I think you set s='default' right in the function declaration.

Comment: Thank you, Cooper

This worked out:

`function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Staffing Data');
  var r = s.getRange(1,2,s.getLastRow());
  var v = r.getValues();
  var x = s.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]== x)
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};`